# Set up of environment variable PATH in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, unix, environment-variables

The Environment PATH is much larger in PROD as compared to QA:

```
PATH=.:/home/imc:/home/imc/bin:$HOME:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

We are using the same setup environment file in PROD and QA but we still find difference.

The longer path means it effects while running the job. So any idea how to improve the PATH?

Comment: Setting PATH in this way only prepends some values to the existing value. So you need to check where the `PATH` is being set prior to running your setup file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both QA and PROD use the same assignment statement for PATH in their `.bashrc` **and do not reference `$PATH`**. That way you can guarantee the PATHs are identical, no matter what other startup files executed prior to `.bashrc` are used to modify `PATH`. E.g.

```
# Assign a short and sweet PATH.
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH):$HOME/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

Note that placing `.` in a `PATH` is a boo-boo for security reasons. On another note, the number of directories in `PATH` is very likely **not** impacting speed of scripts. Bash keeps a hash of utility locations and lookup durations are not far from constant time.

Comment: Hi jens, Thanks for the reply but when i used the command  echo $PATH  it is showing another different path.

Comment: Then you are not using the same startup files. Place `echo Here` statements in `.bashrc` and `.profile` to verify which one is run. Another reason might be that PROD and QA use different Linux systems. What does `uname -a` output in both cases?

Comment: Linux tryprimpfapp1.intra.searshc.com 2.6.18-194.17.4.el5xen #1 SMP Wed Oct 20 13:11:50 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Any chance PROD and QA are using different shells? (Say, ksh, zsh, pdksh, ash)? What does echo $SHELL say for PROD and QA?

Comment: come out same for prod and QA

Comment: /bin/bash for both. Can i send you both the path which is displaying